# How to do a group by aggregation in Python with filter and date transformation

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the below dataset and want to sum the values based on vendor and month taken from the date whilst also applying a filter that returns only the first Monday of each month.

```
date      vendor   value
07/01/19  Amazon   10
07/01/19  Amazon   500
04/02/19  ebay     60
04/03/19  Amazon   130
06/03/19  ebay     20
25/03/19  pcworld  250
```

I believe pandas would be the best way forward but I'm new to python so wouldn't know.

```
vendor  month   value
Amazon  1       510
Amazon  3       130
ebay    2       60
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
#You data appears to be dayfirst

df_filt = df.where((df['date'].dt.dayofweek == 0) & (df['date'].dt.day < 8)).dropna(how='all')
#Filter out all data whre date isn't on monday nor in the first seven day of a month
df_fil.groupby(['vendor',df_fil['date'].dt.month])['value'].agg('sum').reset_index().rename(columns={'date':'month'})
#groupby with agg
```

Output:

```
   vendor  month  value
0  Amazon      1  510.0
1  Amazon      3  130.0
2    ebay      2   60.0
```

Comment: I like the checking `day < 8` - I was trying to do something in my deleted answer involving `pd.DateOffset` to direct get the date of the first Monday for the month but couldn't quite get it to work...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you.  I appreciate the comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott, this helped me perfectly. I wouldn't have thought of the day < 8 bit!

Comment: One question though, how does this code pick up the data for this? i can't see it anywhere

Comment: Oh... I am using jupyter notebooks and I highlighted your data and in the question above the copied and used pd.read_clipboard() to paste data into jupyter notebook.